# how to change string order inside of brackets in notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

How to change this:

```
differentlenghttext[anynumber,9E+09,9E+09,9E+09,9E+09,9E+09]
```

to

```
differentlenghttext[9E+09,anynumber,9E+09,9E+09,9E+09,9E+09]
```

Comment: Did you try something? What type is `anynumber`? Integer, float... Please, give some real sample strings and expected result.

Comment: ex: 15.0302 or 33.7310

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\[([^,]+),([^,]+)`
- Replace with: `$2,$1`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\[              # openning square bracket
([^,]+)         # group 1, 1 or more non comma
,               # a comma
([^,]+)         # group 2, 1 or more non comma
```

[image]